# create an XML file to store the input in my Android app

Tags: java, android, xml, storage

I work with Android Studio and have two input values ​​and these should be saved in an XML file. How do I create an XML file in my App to save my input? I already tried it with the XmlSerializer but I don't understand where I can find the generated file in my app

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText mEditTextG;
EditText mEditTextS;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void send (View v) throws FileNotFoundException {
    mEditTextG = findViewById(R.id.editTextGERID);
    String gerID = mEditTextG.getText().toString();

    mEditTextS = findViewById(R.id.editTextSollAstID);
    String sollID = mEditTextS.getText().toString();

    //create XML File for Storage
String filename = "device.xml";
XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
try {
    serializer.setOutput(writer);
    serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
        serializer.startTag("", "device");
         serializer.startTag("", "GERID");
         serializer.text(gerID);
         serializer.endTag("","GERID");

         serializer.startTag("", "SollAstID");
         serializer.text(sollID);
         serializer.endTag("","SollAstID");
        serializer.endTag("","device");
    serializer.endDocument();
    String result = writer.toString();
    FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(result.getBytes(),0,result.length());
    fos.close();
    Toast.makeText(this,"SollID: "+ sollID ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

   
}
```

[This is how the XML file should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnSGI.png)

The XML file should also be able to be displayed or read in later in the program.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please remove images and post all text as text.

Comment: `How do I create an XML file in Android Studio` I think you mean: in my Android app.

Comment: Post your code as code not the pictures

Comment: Your question is confusing, please try and describe it better.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Creating an XML file in Java is discussed in dozens of questions here on SO and saving a private file on Android, too.

Comment: @Robert I have tried it with the XmlSerializer to create the XML file but i don't understand where i can find the generated file in my app

Comment: @Robert Thank you for your answer.
I have one more question: If I run the app again, the previous entries are deleted (understandable) But how can I save the values ​​in the XML file so that they are not deleted every time without a database connection?

Comment: What values are you talking about?

Comment: @Robert I mean the Input (string) values which i save in the XML file.

Comment: Once you have written the XML file containing the values of course on next app start you have to read the file,, deseralize it and show the values. Make yourself familiar with the Android activity lifecycle where you have to implement storing of the entered values (onCreate is not a good point for storing user input).